# Error:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

Tags: python, image, image-processing, ocr

I am getting the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'

while running the below script for OCR:

```
import Image
from tesseract import image_to_string


print(image_to_string(Image.open('marlboro.png'), lang='eng'))
```

I am using Spider through Anaconda and have Pillow installed.

Comment: When I had this issue, I re-installed pytesseract and it worked. Sometimes it's as easy as that.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html), where you can see some basic examples. In short: You need to specify that you are importing `Image` from `PIL`:

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Thanks i chagnged this to, which removed the previous error but a new one popped up  - 

from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

print(image_to_string(Image.open('marlboro.png')))




But i am getting a new error now -

Answer (score 0):

You should install `pytesseract` use pip (also see [guide](https://grimhacker.com/2014/11/23/installing-pytesseract-practically-painless/)):

```
pip install pytesseract
```

and then:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string

print(image_to_string(Image.open('marlboro.png'), lang='eng'))
```

or use python cross-platform module `tesseract`:

```
pip install tesseract
```

and use it as you have in your question:

```
from PIL import Image
from tesseract import image_to_string

print(image_to_string(Image.open('marlboro.png'), lang='eng'))
```

Comment: I am getting the following error now - 
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Comment: have you installed tesseract?

Comment: try to run your IDE as administrator

Comment: unfortunately its my office laptop and there is no admin privilages available for us

Comment: so you don't have permissions  on your Anaconda files

Comment: Ahhh.. I dint get you ?i can access and install packages in anaconda

Comment: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2893
read this maybe it helps you

Comment: but it is administrator issue, if you run your Anaconda as administrator, everything will be ok. Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605539/permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-denied-c-program-files-anaconda3-p

Comment: thanks @godot for your help . I restarted it again and ran it as an admin and it worked phew ...